# Do object-oriented programming languages exist that are not class-based?

Tags: programming-languages, object-oriented

Are there any [object-oriented programming languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-oriented_programming_languages) that are not based on the class paradigm?

Comment: Technically speaking, C.  Though *oriented* is quite a stretch in the sense of the language making it easy.  I know that's not the kind of answer you are looking for, but if you care to look into how C can do it, it might provide some insight into what it is that classes actually do and how alternative approaches can work.

Comment: @kylben:  "Oriented" is an uncalled-for stretch.  You can bludgeon C into object-oriented behavior.  You can't bludgeon it into being oriented that way.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

As far as I know, [**Self**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self_%28programming_language%29) is the original language that invented the "class-free" paradigm based on [prototypes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming). It already existed (in an experimental stage) in the 1980s and pushes [Smalltalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk)'s elegant usage of the [prototype pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern) to the extreme, such that classes are completely eliminated.

It influenced all the other "class-free" OO languages I know of:

- most prominently Javascript,
- the classical programming language and environment [Squeak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeak) (which is built on top of Smalltalk)
- the multi-paradigm script language [Lua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_%28programming_language%29).

Comment: I upvoted your answer, as it is the most complete and informative; although, I think that it is very debatable whether Lua can be considered object-oriented. I've always thought of it as a pretty straightforward procedural language with some syntactic sugar that allows its associative arrays to look and feel like objects.

Comment: It is OO, insofar as you can implement all of the major themes- encapsulation, polymorphism, and inheritance- within the language without *too* much hassle.

Comment: @Adam: without static typing, isn't it ALL just syntactic sugar?

Comment: [Here is an article](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/lua/luaoop.htm) giving some possibilities on how to implement OOP using Lua's "syntactic sugar" based on first-class functions and tables.

Comment: @DeadMG OO language is not the one which enables you to implement OO ideas but one which does it for you :)

Comment: Actually, both Simula (1960) and Smalltalk-71 (as well as Smalltalk-72) didn't have classes, either, which predates Self by almost three decades. Classes were only added in Simula-67 and Smalltalk-74 (and Alan Kay considered them a mistake, or more precisely a necessary evil).

Comment: @kevincline: Not sure what you're basing that on; OO and static typing are completely orthogonal.

Comment: @Jörg: Thanks for the information (+1). Another innovation that Smalltalk braught :) Your comment led to [this question about Smalltalk innovations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875007/which-innovations-like-mvc-xunit-hotspot-did-smalltalk-bring).

Comment: Apart from Simula (which did take on the class paradigm) Flavors was introduced at MIT in 1979, and was a precursor to CLOS, both of which predate Self.

Comment: OOP and static typing are orthogonal. Classes and static typing are not completely orthogonal, as when they come with dynamic dispatch, they are a way to enable some extra flexibility in a statically typed environment.

Comment: @yeoman: yes, of course there is OOP for statically and dynamically typed languages. But is OOP and static typing really orthogonal? Doesn't dynamic dispatch bring a sort of dynamic typing even into a statically typed language (even for purely statically typed languages as http://mlton.org/ObjectOrientedProgramming)? Yes, there is static dispatching for OOP with inheritance (eg via CRTP), but the ones I know are harder and restricted.

Comment: Though a bit outdated, https://adtmag.com/Articles/2001/07/13/Static-vs-Dynamic-Issues-in-ObjectOriented-Programming-Languages.aspx?p=1 touches on all static typing, dynamic typing, and classes.

Comment: Yes, just what I said. Dynamic dispatch creates extra flexibility. Has nothing to do with OOP, though. OOP is not about classes, inheritance or dynamic dispatch at all. It's only about responsibilities and behavior.

Answer (score 31):

Languages like JavaScript are [based on prototypes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based), where behavior is reused by cloning existing objects. The Wikipedia article that I linked to indicates that Lua, ActionScript, and a number of other languages follow this paradigm.

Comment: Any ECMAScript variant uses the prototype paradigm.

Comment: Well, almost any variant. ActionScript (the Flash language) uses classes, although the underlying VM might be implementing them in terms of prototypes.

Comment: @mjfgates, Actionscript 2 used to be ECMAScript based and resembled Javascript a lot.  Actionscript 3 is moving away from that, but still holds its dynamic nature.  You can strong/weak type any variable since in essence everything is an Object.

Answer (score 13):

The most popular object-oriented programming language in the world doesn't have classes, it's called Javascript and is prototype based : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming

Comment: "Most popular object-oriented programming language in the world"? I'm not sure about that claim at all.

Comment: @ThomasOwens, due to its inclusion on the web, you can easily say that every modern web-enabled platform (including mobile devices) has a JavaScript interpreter included. That's a very strong case that it is currently the most popular prototype based language in existance. (unless you think you can make a similar argument for "SELF")

Comment: Javascript is certainly one of the most widely-used programming languages in the world, but I'd expect most usages to be plain old imperative or procedural, with maybe a bit of aspect-oriented programming (callbacks? AJAX? event handlers?) here and there, so calling javascript the 'most popular OOP language' isn't quite justified.

Comment: I would also say "ubiquitous" in order to sidestep a discussion on the merits of its popularity.

Comment: Technically it's ECMAScript that's the most popular, simply because it's a superset to JS and ActionScript (which is used in flash)

Comment: @tdammers, no one called it the most popular OOP language. It is the most popular OOP language that does not have classes. BIG distinction.

Comment: @Stargazer712: I don't like being a language bigot, but he does claim that "the most popular object-oriented programming language in the world [ed: Javascript] doesn't have classes". It can be decomposed of two claims: "Javascript is the most popular object oriented programming language" and "Javascript doesn't have classes"; both of which, I agree with.

Comment: @Stargazer712: Basically what Lie Ryan said. In fact, this is the only decomposition that makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

Object-orientation is an umbrella term for several important concepts that are only partly contingent upon each other. For instance, inheritance can be declared on a case-by-case basis between instances rather than between classes, or the entire class can be represented by a concrete  `prototype` object, as Thomas wrote. It's just more usual to separate structure description from instance creation. Similarly, late binding means that objects with nominally the same method don't necessarily do the same thing when it is invoked, and that the decision is made at runtime. That is likewise possible with the prototype-based approach. And encapsulation is essentially completely independent of whether your objects are instances of declared classes or not.

That said, most OO languages are firmly in the class-based camp. But even then there are idioms that blur the line: the domain-driven design often leads to systems in which the identity of particular objects is much more important than the static class diagram, and decorators allow objects of the same class or interface to have very different behavior.

Answer (score 6):

[Fortress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortress_%28programming_language%29) is an object-oriented language based on traits instead of classes. The difference is mainly in implementation composition. An object's behavior (method definitions) is still determined by the declarations at a specific point in the program text. So in that sense it's similar to class-based systems.

There are object calculi (by Cardelli, I think), that are purely object-based. Every method is an instance member. You form new objects by taking the contents of an existing object and adding, removing, or replacing some of its members. It's slightly different from prototypes, since the new object has no link to the old object, just some of its contents.

IIRC, it's possible to program in a similar way using Python and other hashtable-oriented languages: you can add a function as an instance member and then call it as a method.

Answer (score 5):

Ada, as of its 1995 revision, Ada is object-oriented, but unlike a lot of other OO languages it doesn't combine object-oriented types and modules into a single construct called a "class".  Rather than declaring a type as "class Foo", and putting all the associated method declarations inside the class declaration, you declare a *package* and declare the type (as a `record`) and other things inside the package.  It's not "class-free" in the way that some of the other mentioned languages are, it's just a slightly different way of organizing things.

Ada 95's object-oriented features were added onto the existing 1983 version of the language; it extended the existing record and package constructs to support inheritance et al.

Comment: that's what I remembered, also you need to pass your record to each member function

Comment: @Nikko: That is what happens behind the scenes in every object-oriented language, and fairly explicitly in Python and CLOS (common lisp).

Answer (score 5):

[Io](http://www.iolanguage.com) is another prototype-based object-oriented language. It actually draws inspiration from several of the languages already mentioned in other answers.

> Io is a dynamic prototype-based programming language. The ideas in Io
>   are mostly inspired by Smalltalk (all values are objects), Self
>   (prototype-based), NewtonScript (differential inheritance), Act1
>   (actors and futures for concurrency), Lisp (code is a runtime
>   inspectable / modifiable tree) and Lua (small, embeddable).

Answer (score 4):

Erlang. And yes, Erlang *is* an object-oriented language, as it fulfills all three points of the definition of OO.